# How to pass a string larger than 200 character to a stored procedure via param

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, stored-procedures, large-data

I got stuck with one problem, in my code i have to make a sum request of all article that is present in my datatable, i concatenate all article ID in one string like 'a1,a2,a3' and this is supposed to work.

But i have large ID and around 150 article, so the string i try to pass to the stored procedure is around 1300 characters and this is truncate at 200 characters when it goes to the stored procedure.

Do you know any solution to pass a large string to a stored procedure without SQL Server to truncate this string?

I can write here the C# code or SQL stored procedure if it can help you to help me.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetChargePetrin]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@articlesList varchar(MAX)
AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT 
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa01 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa1',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa02 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa2',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa03 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa3',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa04 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa4',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa05 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa5',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa06 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa6',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa07 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa7',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa08 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa8',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa09 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa9',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa10 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa10',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa11 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa11',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa12 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa12',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa13 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa13',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa14 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa14',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa15 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa15',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa16 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa16',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa17 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa17',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa18 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa18',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa19 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa19',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa20 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa20',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa21 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa21',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa22 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa22',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa23 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa23',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa24 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa24',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa25 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa25',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa26 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa26',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa27 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa27',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa28 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa28',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa29 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa29',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa30 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa30',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa31 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa31',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa32 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa32',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa33 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa33',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa34 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa34',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa35 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa35',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa36 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa36',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa37 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa37',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa38 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa38',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa39 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa39',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa40 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa40',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa41 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa41',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa42 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa42',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa43 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa43',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa44 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa44',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa45 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa45',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa46 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa46',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa47 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa47',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa48 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa48',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa49 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa49',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa50 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa50',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa51 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa51',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa52 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa52',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa53 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa53',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa54 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa54',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa55 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa55',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa56 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa56',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa57 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa57',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa58 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa58',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa59 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa59',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa60 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa60'
        FROM [PDP_TTP].[dbo].[PDP] p
        inner join [PDP_TTP].[dbo].[Articles] a ON a.Division=p.Division and a.Code_article=p.Code_article
        WHERE CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT) >0 and a.Code_article IN( SELECT Id = Item FROM dbo.SplitInts(@articlesList, ','));

END
```

Comment: We'll need to see your stored proc. Chances are that param is `varchar(200)` for example and then the answer is obvious!

Comment: You should look into table valued parameters instead of passing delimited strings. When you pass delimited strings you either have to split them or expose a sql injection vulnerability via dynamic sql.

Comment: If the stored proc is accepting parameter with type varchar(200) then it will truncate the input value to the limit. If that is the case then you need to change the capacity of that parameter to something bigger which suits your requirement. Also make sure that the table in which you are inserting the data that also has the column with appropriate capacity.

Comment: So the stored proc isnt limiting the length, perhaps the C# specifies a length of 200 for that parameter (something does, by all accounts). Perhaps instead of asking us to guess, you could start by debugging your code!

Comment: I just add the stored procedure in the original post. Just to inform, when i test the stored procedure within SQL Server with a large string larger than 1300 characters, it works well. And my code is all good, i send the string with all the ID and it makes a string of 1341 characters, it only turns into 200 characters into the stored procedure

Comment: ....so by process of elimination, what do you think it might be? (hint: see my previous comment)

Comment: I found the problem... i use some .cs file that is handling the exec of all sql command and i had a `p.Size = 200;` in the method that is adding Sql parameter. My bad and thanks all for making me sure that was not a problem inside SQL Server and dig deep down inside my code !

Comment: With the last update which included the sample query I would urge you to normalize this table. Qa1-60 screams of a horrible design and violates 1NF by having repeating columns. Consider how painful it would be to add Qa70-90. You would have to add 20 new columns to every single query. If this was properly normalized you would add new rows instead and none of your queries would have to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Sean Lange's comment, and would suggest to use a table valued parameter instead of sending a string and parsing it in sql
To do that, you need to create a user defined table type in your sql server:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.ArticleIds as table
(
    Id varchar(10) -- should be the same as Code_article definition!
)
GO
```

and then use it as

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetChargePetrin]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @articlesList dbo.ArticleIds readonly -- Must be readonly!
AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT 
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa01 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa1',
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa02 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa2',
        -- ... more of the same
        CAST(SUM(CAST(Qa60 AS INT) /CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT)) AS varchar) as 'qa60'
        FROM [PDP_TTP].[dbo].[PDP] p
        INNER JOIN [PDP_TTP].[dbo].[Articles] a ON a.Division=p.Division AND a.Code_article=p.Code_article
        INNER JOIN @articlesList al ON a.Code_article = al.Id
        WHERE CAST(a.CO_UQB_PET AS INT) > 0 

END
```

To execute a stored procedure with a table valued parameter from c# using ADO.NET, you need to send a parameter with type `SqlDbType.Structured` and pass a `DataTable` as it's value.

Comment: I will use your solution. At first i didn't think of the fact that i'll have more than 500 article in the future so i need your solution to be able to handle that number of article. Thanks

Comment: I just finish implementing and testing your solution and it's working great, thanks you for taking time to show me the best solution with sql example, you saved my day !

Answer (score 0):

I had `p.Size = 200;` inside my method that is adding the Sql parameters, i had to change it to `p.Size = 8000;` and it's working.

Thanks everybody for the help !

Comment: This will work until you exceed 8,000 characters. It would be much better for scalability, performance and maintainability to build this process so it doesn't matter how many values you have. This is where the table valued parameter really excels. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx